# Unable to convert between 1d and 2d array values

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, 2d

I realize this problem and solutions are all over StackOverflow [like here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44653/turning-1d-array-to-2d-array-in-tictactoe) however I'm still unable to make this work.

Most of the examples say that I just need to multiply the row by the width and add the column meaning the location (4, 3) in a 4x4 square grid would become (3 * 4 + 4) or 16. So far so good.

The examples say to get back the coordinates, I should divide the index by the number of rows for x and get the modulo of the index for y. For the example above, that should be...

```
int x = 16 / 4;
int y = 16 % 4;
```

But this works for some values, and not others. In this case, when I get back the coordinates after converting to an index, I get (4,0). This makes sense since 4 goes into 16 evenly so I must be missing something basic.

Here's some test Java code that I've created for trying to figure this out. I should mention that I'm indexing started at 1 so the first square in the upper left corner is 1,1 and the last square would be 4,4.

```
public class Test {

    int size;

    public Test(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int toIndex(int x, int y) {
        return x * this.size + y;
    }

    public int[] toCoordinates(int index) {
        int coordinates[] = new int[2];
        coordinates[0] = index / this.size;
        coordinates[1] = index % this.size;
        return coordinates;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testSize = 4;
        Test test = new Test(testSize);

        for (int i = 1; i <= testSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= testSize; j++) {
                int index = test.toIndex(i, j);
                int coordinates[] = test.toCoordinates(index);
                System.out.println(index + " == " + coordinates[0] + "," + coordinates[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the current code is

```
5 == 1,1
6 == 1,2
7 == 1,3
8 == 2,0
9 == 2,1
10 == 2,2
11 == 2,3
12 == 3,0
13 == 3,1
14 == 3,2
15 == 3,3
16 == 4,0
17 == 4,1
18 == 4,2
19 == 4,3
20 == 5,0
```

Comment: Upper left is 0,0 and bottom right is 3,3. 0 ist the first number!

Comment: I'm guessing your confusion is stemming from using 1-indexed arrays. Java uses 0-indexed arrays, and I would strongly recommend you do the same.

Comment: That's it! I just needed to add 1 to size when doing calculations.

Comment: I haven't used SO in some time and since these were comments, what is the acceptable way to mark this issue as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All arrays start by 0, try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int testSize = 4;
    Test test = new Test(testSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < testSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < testSize; j++) {
            int index = test.toIndex(i, j);
            int coordinates[] = test.toCoordinates(index);
            System.out.println(index + " == " + coordinates[0] + "," + coordinates[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 == 0,0
1 == 0,1
2 == 0,2
3 == 0,3
4 == 1,0
5 == 1,1
6 == 1,2
7 == 1,3
8 == 2,0
9 == 2,1
10 == 2,2
11 == 2,3
12 == 3,0
13 == 3,1
14 == 3,2
15 == 3,3   (16th)
```

Comment: Starting with 0 on arrays is right. Also note that on David's answer his index he is printing starts with 0. In your example output your first index output is 5.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the indexing was the issue. I still need 1 as the index because this plugs into something else that requires it however I solved the problem by incrementing size during the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you swap x and y in your error case. The position should be 19, not 16.

```
Position [4,3] in a 4x4 array is (4*4)+3 = 19
floor(19 / 4) = 4
19 % 4 = 3
```

For the purpose of learning about arrays, I'd strongly recommend sticking to zero-indexed arrays, since they are more intuitively associated with how content is actually stored in memory.